# Can Android applications examine OS wide context, for example network related?

Tags: android

Can Android applications see OS wide context in terms of network? For example,

- what applications are using the network
- what IP addresses is the OS connected to
- etc.

I'm asking because I know each application runs in it's own [Dalvik virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_virtual_machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, generally you cannot see the state of any other applications, nor can you generally get low-level information such as the IP address from the Android framework classes.

However, you could try using the usual `java.net` classes to see whether you get anything back.  For example [`NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces%28%29) should hopefully still give you the expected information as it would on a regular VM.

Alternatively, outwith the Android API you could access networking information as you would on any other Linux system.